# Ошибка сборки под Android после интеграции SnapKit | Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Дело в том, что я захотел использовать в своём приложении данный ассет:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/snap-kit-sdk-184712

Но после интеграции и попытки сборки на Scripting Backend = IL2CPP возникает данная ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код первой ошибки:

```html
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.0/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.0/il2cpp.exe" --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARM64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.9f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.9f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --baselib-directory="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.9f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\arm64-v8a" --avoid-dynamic-library-copy --tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.9f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK" --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.9f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory="C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput"  

stdout:
Running il2cpp.exe in server GC mode.
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a
    Cache directory: C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 129 of which compiled: 0
Total compilation time: 373 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\bogda\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5CB1.tmp" -o "C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_1DD8F0F10E54938E7002B9ED76C9209F\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id -stdlib=libc++ -static-libstdc++ -target aarch64-linux-android21 -Wl,--wrap,sigaction "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\arm64-v8a\baselib.a" -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `CreativeKitIos__creativeKitShare_m685169CA46C01BBEBECB8B611DDE0EA8D661A6DC':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:3172: undefined reference to `_creativeKitShare'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:3172: undefined reference to `_creativeKitShare'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitLogin_m73CD5EE8FC51B06127DFFE39E8A6F9E2ABDE01F0':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4073: undefined reference to `_snapKitLogin'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos_Login_mAB2C8D0456D5A22539A30DF4DA33F52E6E9A0025':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4073: undefined reference to `_snapKitLogin'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitIsLoggedIn_m896EB8EFD0F9240964C9987ED059FCABA26BB614':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4091: undefined reference to `_snapKitIsLoggedIn'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4091: undefined reference to `_snapKitIsLoggedIn'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitVerify_m7973C3604C60C3FB961BEC4C28D82561A46B10E4':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4118: undefined reference to `_snapKitVerify'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitUnlinkAllSessions_mACC37F620F4D6F2FFCDF820072A4DFD687646F62':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4146: undefined reference to `_snapKitUnlinkAllSessions'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos_UnlinkAllSessions_m05C1C22B019FBD501A542F1FDB658AEE057893ED':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4146: undefined reference to `_snapKitUnlinkAllSessions'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitGetAccessToken_m4237F5FF2E9FE80B10ADF767092327658ECA55A6':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4164: undefined reference to `_snapKitGetAccessToken'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4164: undefined reference to `_snapKitGetAccessToken'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitHasAccessToScope_mFE9C72AB9024AE38909331F516474A4DC018A12C':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4195: undefined reference to `_snapKitHasAccessToScope'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4195: undefined reference to `_snapKitHasAccessToScope'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitFetchUserDataWithQuery_mBF2F8F186ECABE0A904C660D390C515703AE1326':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4227: undefined reference to `_snapKitFetchUserDataWithQuery'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Compilation.CompilationDriver.Run(RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:
Unhandled exception. Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\bogda\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5CB1.tmp" -o "C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_1DD8F0F10E54938E7002B9ED76C9209F\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id -stdlib=libc++ -static-libstdc++ -target aarch64-linux-android21 -Wl,--wrap,sigaction "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\arm64-v8a\baselib.a" -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `CreativeKitIos__creativeKitShare_m685169CA46C01BBEBECB8B611DDE0EA8D661A6DC':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:3172: undefined reference to `_creativeKitShare'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:3172: undefined reference to `_creativeKitShare'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitLogin_m73CD5EE8FC51B06127DFFE39E8A6F9E2ABDE01F0':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4073: undefined reference to `_snapKitLogin'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos_Login_mAB2C8D0456D5A22539A30DF4DA33F52E6E9A0025':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4073: undefined reference to `_snapKitLogin'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitIsLoggedIn_m896EB8EFD0F9240964C9987ED059FCABA26BB614':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4091: undefined reference to `_snapKitIsLoggedIn'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4091: undefined reference to `_snapKitIsLoggedIn'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitVerify_m7973C3604C60C3FB961BEC4C28D82561A46B10E4':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4118: undefined reference to `_snapKitVerify'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitUnlinkAllSessions_mACC37F620F4D6F2FFCDF820072A4DFD687646F62':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4146: undefined reference to `_snapKitUnlinkAllSessions'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos_UnlinkAllSessions_m05C1C22B019FBD501A542F1FDB658AEE057893ED':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4146: undefined reference to `_snapKitUnlinkAllSessions'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitGetAccessToken_m4237F5FF2E9FE80B10ADF767092327658ECA55A6':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4164: undefined reference to `_snapKitGetAccessToken'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4164: undefined reference to `_snapKitGetAccessToken'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitHasAccessToScope_mFE9C72AB9024AE38909331F516474A4DC018A12C':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4195: undefined reference to `_snapKitHasAccessToScope'
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4195: undefined reference to `_snapKitHasAccessToScope'
C:/Users/bogda/Desktop/Unity/New Unity Project/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/FA0E2887AB59106DB81B547E913204E5.o: In function `LoginKitIos__snapKitFetchUserDataWithQuery_mBF2F8F186ECABE0A904C660D390C515703AE1326':
C:\Users\bogda\Desktop\Unity\New Unity Project\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Snap.cpp:4227: undefined reference to `_snapKitFetchUserDataWithQuery'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Compilation.CompilationDriver.Run(RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <cdc1918cb795429dbbd46f2de52cb053>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Однако при сборке на Scripting Backend = Mono всё билдится без проблем. Но такой способ компиляции уже не актуален.

Написал в поддержку SnapKit`a - не отвечают.

Как мне решить данную проблему? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Оберни полностью код в этих скриптах LoginKit.iOS и CreativeKit.iOS

```
#if UNITY_IOS
#endif
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло мне скомпилировать проект. Однако приложение не запускается) Даже не показывается заставка Unity - просто вылетает практически сразу. Не знаете в чём может быть проблема? Проект пустой - в него интегрирован только snapkit SDK.

Comment: Делал доп. пункты для иос из readme файла?

Comment: Можешь еще попробовать добавить в podfile, если этого нет и сделать pod deintegrate && pod install

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  pod 'SnapSDK', '1.6.8', :subspecs => ['SCSDKLoginKit', 'SCSDKCreativeKit']
end